# Wubi.exe won’t start

Tags: 64-bit, wubi

I'm currently using Win7 64bit. I right clicked "wubi.exe" and chose "run as administrator", then nothing happened. I have "ubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.iso" and "wubi.exe" in the same folder.
Thanks.

Comment: Please file such things as bugs. It's not a question. Launchpad.net is much better suited to handling these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions to run Wubi are [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

[Specifically relating to your question](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_download_and_install_a_32_bit_version_of_Ubuntu.3F):

You are attempting to install a 32bit version of ubuntu into your 64bit O/S.  If this was intentional then

> To modify arguments, right-click Wubi.exe and select "Create
>   Shortcut". Then right-click the shortcut, select Properties, and
>   modify the Target line, for example: "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Desktop\wubi.exe" --32bit

Otherwise, download the 64bit ubuntu ISO and install via wubi by double clicking the exe.

Answer (score 1):

Just Copy wubi.exe
and the iso file to
c:\

and it will work fine

Comment: It works for me, I put `wubi.exe` and the iso in `S:\ `, nothing happend, but put in `C:\ `, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right version of wubi.exe. For 10.04.2 you get it from http://release.ubuntu.com/lucid
But that doesn't explain why 'nothing happened'. Wubi will ignore the wrong iso and download the right version.

Sometimes you can have problems if you have a different version of python installed. You could go to the %temp% directory and remove all py* files and directories. See if that makes a difference.

While you're in the %temp% directory, check for a log file wubi-10.04.2-rev191.log and post that if it exists.

Comment: Hey, i have same problem, and i do have multiple python installations on my system, deleted anything python releated from %temp%, and i do not see any logs.
Also, file starts, but it exits after starting (if i run it from console, file executes and i get next cmd prompt entry)

Comment: When I was running a debuggable version of wubi, I found that I had to copy python23.dll into the current directory before it would work. Python doesn't seem very backwards-compatible so it's possible that if it finds a later runtime - it simply doesn't work (that's what I'd guess is happening).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, fixed it by removing all python instances from PATH and PYTHONPATH.

To do that, just press start, write PATH, and you should have entry saying Edit Environment variables or similar, open it, you can delete PATH and PYTHONPATH there (or just modify them temporarily like i did)

In my situation i used mint4win, but it happens with all(?) wubi based installers.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would download the wubi executable from ubuntu website and then try that. For a good internet speed, you are looking at max 60secs. and you're ready to roll. The reason for this - is because if you manage to fire the wubi.exe you currently have, it would still connect and pull the download files from the web. Unless you have a way around it to use the directory files, I personally will go the easy way.